# Golang: how to mock ...interface{} arguents using gomock

Tags: go, mocking, printf, gomock

I have a `Printer` interface that uses the standard go `Printf` function signature:

```
type Printer interface {
    Printf(format string, tokens ...interface{})
}
```

I would like to be able to mock this interface using [gomock](https://github.com/golang/mock), but I'm not sure how setup the `tokens ...interface{}` argument properly.

I expected that `Printf(gomock.Any(), gomock.Any())` would cover all potential cases (since `tokens` compiles to `[]interface{}`), but it appears you need to setup an explicit call for N number of tokens:

```
// no tokens
mockPrinter.EXPECT().
    Printf(gomock.Any()).
    AnyTimes()

// 1 token
mockPrinter.EXPECT().
    Printf(gomock.Any(), gomock.Any()).
    AnyTimes()

// 2 tokens
mockPrinter.EXPECT().
    Printf(gomock.Any(), gomock.Any(), gomock.Any()).
    AnyTimes()

// ... up to N tokens
```

Does anyone know of a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Not possible with the current version of gomock. Maybe you can extend it, and send a pull request in. To understand why it's not possible, you have to look at the mock generated for variadic functions.

To do that, let's look at the examples in gomock's repository, specifically [./sample/mock_user/user.go](https://github.com/rafrombrc/gomock/blob/9dcd4b2cd01be60f9fbabacce2a6ae1ed21ea48f/sample/user.go) and [./sample/mock_user/mock_user.go](https://github.com/rafrombrc/gomock/blob/9dcd4b2cd01be60f9fbabacce2a6ae1ed21ea48f/sample/mock_user/mock_user.go).

#### Generated Mock

You'll see a function in the *Index* inteface called *Ellip*, which is like your *Printf* function:

```
type Index interface {
    // ...
    Ellip(fmt string, args ...interface{})
    // ...
}
```

Now, here's what the mocked function looks like for *Ellip*:

```
func (_m *MockIndex) Ellip(_param0 string, _param1 ...interface{}) {
    _s := []interface{}{_param0}
    for _, _x := range _param1 {
        _s = append(_s, _x)
    }
    _m.ctrl.Call(_m, "Ellip", _s...)
}
```

Notice anything odd? Well, gomock is creating a slice of interfaces, **_s**, initialized with the first parameter. Then it appends the variadic parameters to that slice of interfaces, **_s**.

So, to be clear, it doesn't just append the variadic parameter, **_param1**, to the slice. Each individual variadic from **_param1** is appended to the new slice, by iterating through it.

This means that the slice of variadic parameters is not preserved. It's broken out.

Answer (score 0):

As of October 1, 2017, `gomock.Any()` works correctly for variadic args: https://github.com/golang/mock/pull/101